# Pay Integration into a WinForms project

Tags: paypal

Which PayPal API is best for credit card transactions from a WinForms C# Point of Sale project (not a Website). I notice that PayPal has partnered with various companies for a iPad Point of Sale application. Does anyone know which API's Vend and ShopKeep are using for there PayPal integration.

Thanks,
Bob H

Answer (score 1):

I called PayPal Technical support and they told me is that the only product they support to enter credit card information without a website is the 'Terminal' program.  The terminal program involves the business entering the information manually. May be useful in some situations but not what I was looking for in this case.